# renaming two different file extensions in one batch file

Tags: batch-file, file-rename

I have this code segment:

```
SET PREFIX=pic
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.jpg') DO (call :renum "%%G")
GOTO :eof

:renum
 ren %1 %PREFIX%%count%.jpg
 set /a count+=1
 GOTO :eof
```

For renaming all the `jpg` files. I'd like to add the same thing for `mp4`, but editing the `jpg` to `mp4` doesn't work.

How can I rename them both? (I think it's related to the `oef` label.)

Comment: Have you replaced *both* `.jpg` with `.mp4`?

Comment: If the prefix for `jpg` files will be `pic`, what should the prefix be for `mp4` files?

Comment: - Yes, I replaced both occurences. -The mp4 prefix should be "video"

Answer (score 0):

This is untested:

```
@echo off
set count=0
FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /b /a-d *.jpg') DO call :renum "%%G" "pic"
set count=0
FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /b /a-d *.mp4') DO call :renum "%%G" "video"
echo done
pause
GOTO :eof

:renum
 set /a count+=1
 echo renaming "%~1" to "%~2%count%%~x1"
 ren "%~1" "%~2%count%%~x1"
 GOTO :eof
```

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but this code doesn't work. Also, it is a mp4 file, not mkv..

Comment: I noticed an extra `%` in two places. Test the above now.  if it fails then show a line or two of what you see on the screen.

Comment: @user2517096 You should accept the answer which will help future Googler.